Is there any way to know when I'm passed the last item while iterating through a dictionary in django template?
I'm trying to create a text representation of a JSONField that has some data structured as an array of dictionaries like this:
[
 {
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2"
 },
 {
  "key3":"value3",
  "key4":"value4",
  "key5":"value5"
 }
]

My goal is to represent this data in the Django template like this:

( key1=value1 & key2=value2 ) || ( key3=value3 & key4=value4 & key5=value5 )

Now I'd iterate through the array and see if I'm not hitting the last dictionary so I can add an || between the condition representation text since it's already an array list like:
{% for dict in data %}
 // Do stuff with dict
 {% if data|last != dict %}
  ||
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

However, since a dictionary doesn't have a last thing, I'm having a hard time to iterate through the "key,value" when I'm doing stuff with each dictionary object when I've got to append an "&" only if I'm not hitting the end of this dict items.
{% for k,v in dict %}
 k=v
 // append "&" if this is not the last key being iterated?
{% endfor %}

Any suggestions/workarounds/ideas would be much appreciated :)

len(dict) will give the number of key value pairs

@ticktalk Thanks for mentioning, although I'm guessing we don't have a len() in django templates? That would be raw python, useful in views, etc.

Just found it! Silly me, Seems like Django already provides a pretty neat built-in forloop object for templates that works like a charm!
Will drop it here for anyone who might have the same problem
{% for k,v in dict %}
 k=v
 {% if forloop.last != True %}
 &amp;
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


Are you trying to format a querystring?

@willeM_VanOnsem I believe so, We're storing some constraints to use as a query filter directly to a JsonField in the model (which I assume is simply a flattened string decoded by django on the fly?) so we can have our own custom permission system that can handle access to objects based on model attributes. Thanks for the advise, will also take a look at your answer ^_^

You can use not, which is probably a bit more readable:
{% for k,v in dict %}
  {{ k }}={{ v }}
  {% if not forloop.last %}
    &amp;
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
But it looks to me you are formatting a query string [wiki]? I would strongly suggest not to format that manually, and also not use template logic, since Django's template engine is not very fast.
Use Django's QueryDict [Django-doc] instead. Indeed, in the view, we can make a QueryDict from a dict with:
from django.http import QueryDict

qd = QueryDict(mutable=True)
qd.update(my_dict)
and render it in the template as:
{{ qd.urlencode }}

Currently it seems like "forloop.last" has worked for what I expected. Thank you for mentioning the "not" though! It certainly feels more readable :)
Also didn't know we have a QueryDict wrapper! nice!
